# Reading a single value in a https request's JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, express

In my Angular I have code that requests a certain User and in that same function I want to catch the json result my server sends, and read one property of this json object.

Example Angular:

```
 $scope.CheckEmail = function () {
    $http.post("/FindUser", {"username": $scope.username})
        .success(function (data) {
            if (isEmpty(data))
                alert("No user Found");
            else
                if(data.email == $scope._id) 
                      alert("found correct user");
        });
}
```

Backend Code:

```
app.post("/CheckEmail", function (req, res) {
   User.find({ "username": req.body.username }, function (err, us) {
       res.json(us);
    })
})
```

But `data.email`is undefined, please tell me how I can read a single field from this JSON response my anguler gets.

Added the screenshot of the console.log(data) here :

---

[image]

Comment: Have you logged `data` and checked what's being returned?

Comment: Not an angular guy but is `data` parsed for you? If not, you need to `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: My Express sends back JSON object of the user it found in the database

Comment: Use the debugger of your web brower to look into the response, or use console.log(data).

Comment: Use `{}` always (good practice, after vulnerability from Apple especially).
And show your backend code which sends this data please.

Comment: what do you see when you log `data` in the success handler?

Comment: use {} where and how? 
@PascalLeMerrer I have checked this, it correctly gives a JSON object of the user it found in database and it does contain the property I want to read. Would you prefer a screenshot or do you believe me? :)

Comment: data is an array, that's why data.email is undefined. You should test data[0].email.

Comment: this works, don't know why I didn't even think about that. thank you so much ;)

Comment: @TomKustermans I think Oleg meant in your code, in your if-else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code :

```
$http.post("/FindUser", {"username": $scope.username})
        .success(function (data)
```

What you getting back is a an array as you have shown in your console log. hence you might have to do something like

```
data[0].email
```

basically you have to process the array, because that is what u getting back